# javascript 'this' usage

Tags: javascript, class, object

let's say I have code like this:

```
var object1 = {};
object1.class1 = function() {
    this.property1 = null;
    this.property2 = 'ab';
}
```

in this case, what does 'this' stand for? object1 or class1? And whenever I want to define a class constructor inside an object, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: link i think help you : http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Comment: I think I learned something just now: object1 can't have another instance. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `class1`, because you can't make an object of type object1.

However, if the code would be:

```
function object1() {
    this.class1 = function() {
        this.property1 = null;
        this.property2 = 'ab';
    }
}
```

You could have:

```
var obj = new object1();
obj.class1();
obj.property2; // => 'ab';

var cls = new obj.class1();
cls.property2; // => 'ab';
```

So it could depend on context.

Comment: That said, I have seen situations where 'this' does refer to object1. Seem that if the properties are already exist within object1, class1 turn into just a mere method. 

Sigh, if only there was a way I can tell for sure.

Comment: @Khoi: No. `this` refers to the object passed as `this` to the method. If you wanted, you could make this refer to another, completely unrelated object, like: `var test = {}; obj.class1.call(test);`, then `test.property2` would be `ab`. `this` depends only on calling context in javascript, not on anything else.

Comment: Yep, that solves the problem. I just have to explicitly define the calling context. Thank you!

Comment: The first line of this answer is incorrect. In OP's example, `this` will refer to `object1` if you call `object1.class1()`. It is also possible to make copies of `object1` using `var object2 = Object.create(object1)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you call it like so:

```
object1.class1();
```

Then `this` will refer to `object1`.